# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException with CompositeComponent?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, propertynotfoundexception

I'm currently trying to build a composite component, and this is how i make use of my component :

---

Include it with `xmlns:albert="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/albert"`

---

And here's the usage example

```
<albert:infoButton
    infoId="infoSingleRecord"
    params="transDateFrom transDateTo"
    mappingMethod="#{tBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB.mapSendInfoSingleRecord}" />
```

---

And this is the component which is put in resources/albert/infoButton.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="infoId" required="true" />
        <composite:attribute name="params" />
        <composite:attribute name="mappingMethod" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <p:commandButton 
            process="@this #{cc.attrs.params}"
            actionListener="#{cc.attrs.mappingMethod}"
            update="#{cc.attrs.infoId}Panel"
            oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.infoId}Dialog.show()" 
            image="ui-icon ui-icon-search" />
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

---

But running it, when clicking the infoButton, this exception trace shows in my catalina.out log file :

```
Apr 25, 2011 10:08:43 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException' when invoking action listener '#{cc.attrs.mappingMethod}' for component 'j_idt71'
Apr 25, 2011 10:08:43 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /TBrowse_tabConfirmedRPB.xhtml @33,77 mappingMethod="#{tBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB.mapSendInfoSingleRecord}": Property 'mapSendInfoSingleRecord' not found on type mywebapp.paymentplan.TBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:450)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:777)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

ERROR BusinessExceptionHandler - BusinessExceptioHandler handles an unhandled exception: 
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /TBrowse_tabConfirmedRPB.xhtml @33,77 mappingMethod="#{tBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB.mapSendInfoSingleRecord}": Property 'mapSendInfoSingleRecord' not found on type mywebapp.paymentplan.TBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:777)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /TBrowse_tabConfirmedRPB.xhtml @33,77 mappingMethod="#{tBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB.mapSendInfoSingleRecord}": Property 'mapSendInfoSingleRecord' not found on type mywebapp.paymentplan.TBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:450)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    ... 24 more
```

---

I wonder why is this happening, because at the mywebapp.paymentplan.TBrowseBean_ConfirmedRPB, i already provide this :

```
public String mapSendInfoSingleRecord(ActionEvent event) {                                                                                                                             
    System.out.println("mapSendInfoSingleRecord");                                                                                                                                 
    return null;                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

---

And after that, i tried putting the dummy mapSendInfoSingleRecord field, and see what happens :

```
private String mapSendInfoSingleRecord;
public String getMapSendInfoSingleRecord() {
    return mapSendInfoSingleRecord;
}

public void setMapSendInfoSingleRecord(String mapSendInfoSingleRecord) {
    this.mapSendInfoSingleRecord = mapSendInfoSingleRecord;
}
```

---

But clicking on the button now produces this exception :

```
Apr 25, 2011 10:32:46 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking action listener '#{cc.attrs.mappingMethod}' for component 'j_idt71'
Apr 25, 2011 10:32:46 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap@12f3802.mappingMethod()
        at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:225)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:777)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

ERROR BusinessExceptionHandler - BusinessExceptioHandler handles an unhandled exception: 
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: Method not found: com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap@12f3802.mappingMethod()
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:777)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap@12f3802.mappingMethod()
        at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:225)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
        ... 24 more
```

---

I've tested against mojarra version 2.0.4-b09 and 2.1.1-b04, with the same results.

---

I wonder what I did wrong here ?

Comment: Shouldn't `xmlns:sofco` be obfuscated as `xmlns:albert`? :)

Comment: @BalusC: Haha, a mindreader. Edited :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

First, the composite `method-signature` which you've definied

```
<composite:attribute name="mappingMethod" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />
```

doesn't match with the real method signature

```
public String mapSendInfoSingleRecord(ActionEvent event)
```

Second, the `actionListener` methods should return `void` not `String`.

I assume that you just want a `action` method, you should then change the real method signature to get rid of the `ActionEvent` argument:

```
public String mapSendInfoSingleRecord()
```

As to `actionListener` vs `action`, you may find this question/answer useful: [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener).

Comment: Wow cool ! After modifying ***method-signature="java.lang.Void action(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)"*** to match ***void mapSendInfoSingleRecord(ActionEvent e)***, everything works smoothly now. And i chose actionListener because im intending to do UI stuffs only on the method, without any business logic calls in there. And why i return String while it's an actionListener method is because i was testing various ways when dealing with the exception, and then getting unsure when defnining void, try to follow the basic examples from the book by using String instead :-) Thank you guru !